# Adding to a collection in an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class school, which can have a number of events...

```
public class School: Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
    public void AddEvent(Event newEvent) 
    {
        Events.Add(newEvent);
    }
}
```

This is the event class

```
public class Event : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a entity-class - not relevant, but if anyone wants to see

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> 
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to add a new event for the school, I call a POST endpoint with the properties of the Event-class.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEvent(Guid schoolId, Event newEvent)
{
     var school = await _context.School.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == schoolId);
     
     school.AddEvent(newEvent);
     
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     
     return Ok();
}
```

However, this for some reason results in this error...

**Full stack trace**:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.TryGet(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, InternalEntityEntry& entry, Boolean throwOnNonUniqueness)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, Boolean throwOnTypeMismatch)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable`1 added, IEnumerable`1 removed)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable`1 added, IEnumerable`1 removed)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectNavigationChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.TryDetectChanges()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MakersOfDenmark.WebAPI.Controllers.EventController.CreateEvent(Guid schoolId, Event newEvent) in C:\Users\mathi\Source\Repos\makersofdenmark\src\MakersOfDenmark.WebAPI\Controllers\EventController.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Elmah.Io.AspNetCore.Serilog.ElmahIoSerilogMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226134/discussion-on-question-by-thesystem-adding-to-a-collection-in-an-entity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add relationship between school and event.

```
public class School: Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();

    public void AddEvent(Event newEvent) 
    {
        Events.Add(newEvent);
    }
}

public class Event : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }
    public School School { get;set; }
    public Guid SchoolId { get;set; }
}


//on your DB context
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasOne(x => x.School).WithMany(x => x.Events);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this out. I will try it right away.

Comment: I am sorry but it gives the exact same error message.

Comment: did you try to recreate database ? or you can add migration and apply it

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought about it. Give me two minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no luck after migration and database update.

Comment: can you send me a image of your database structure ? i am going to make a simple example.

Comment: Working on it right now, should have imgur link ready in five minutes approx

Comment: I have uploaded diagram here: https://imgur.com/a/KWqwh4D

Comment: i made a simple working example for you with in-memory database .. i will upload it somewhere and i will let you know...

Comment: https://github.com/Puko/SchoolTest. There is just one POST endpoint. In this case i just use InMemory database ...

Comment: Thank you so much for such elaborate help, that is extremely helpful. I also thanked you in the chat, but seems like the like to chat-room is gone. The first thing that comes to my mind is, that you have created a DbSet for Event in DbContext, which I havent done.... I suspected that I didn't need to do that, since Events is a property to School? I am a little confused now, because Event surely has a table in my database, as you could see from the diagram. Don't know if that was super obvious and my brain has stopped working... Hmm you think that could be it?

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure if a database table will be created implicitly when it is defined as a property in other object. I never tried it. I always create DbSet for all my database objects.

Comment: I don't know why but it is still teasing me locally, but your solution is the right and my problem seems to be local. And now I have your sample project to refer to, so I am sure I will solve this soon. Again, thank you so so much. You have really made my day a lot better! :)